# 301 Redirect via .htaccess isn't working

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I have about 50 old links which is to be redirected to new links. However, instead of re-directing, I'm sent to 404 page.

This is my htaccess file below. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
## Mod_rewrite in use.

RewriteEngine On

## Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.
# If you experience problems on your site then comment out the operations listed 
# below by adding a # to the beginning of the line.
# This attempts to block the most common type of exploit `attempts` on Joomla!
#
# Block any script trying to base64_encode data within the URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
# Block any script that includes a <script> tag in URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
# Block any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
# Block any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
# Return 403 Forbidden header and show the content of the root homepage
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]
#
## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.

## Begin - Custom redirects
#
# If you need to redirect some pages, or set a canonical non-www to
# www redirect (or vice versa), place that code here. Ensure those
# redirects use the correct RewriteRule syntax and the [R=301,L] flags.
#
## End - Custom redirects

Redirect 301 http://domain.me/blog.php?id=7 http://domain.me/blog
Redirect 301 http://domain.me/iiblg/17-0-The-girl-with.html http://domain.me/blog/the-girl-with
Redirect 301 http://domain.me/iiblg/20-0-Sendra-Lake.html http://domain.me/blog/sendra-lake
```

There's many more links. I just removed it from here.

Comment: Have you enabled .htaccess ??

Comment: Yes I did enabled it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not match against querystring using Redirect directive. You need to use mod-rewrite to do that.

To redirect **example.com/blog.php?id=7** to **example.com/blog** you need the following rule :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=7$
RewriteRule ^blog\.php$ http://example.com/blog/? [NC,L,R]
```

Comment: Thanks but what would the other links look like? The 2 other links since that's the format of the rest of the URLs.

Comment: For links without querystring, you can use Redirect directive (the oldpath can not start with host) , **Redirect 301 /dir/filename.html http://example.com/newfilename/**

Comment: Thank you. Got it working perfectly. Didn't know about the host name.